# Difference between Activity diagram and normal flow specified in Use case specification table

Tags: diagrams

I'm studying use case and activity diagrams and I get confused about the difference between activity diagram and the normal flow specified in the use case specification table, aren't both of them specify the flow of our system ?

[image: Use case specification table]

Comment: Please post text as text rather than images - images are neither accessible nor searchable.

Answer (score 1):

UML does not have strict rules for writing a use case description, and it does not have strict rules for creating activity diagrams. It is up to the analyst or architect to pick a useful level of abstraction and to make a decision about when to draw a diagram and when not. If in your working context (or learning context?) someone gave you the task to create this kind of use case spec table, the "flow of events" could be a candidate for the basis of an activity diagram, which might lead to some overlap, that should be quite obvious.

Whether you actually need to model this flow of event as an activity diagram when you already have a verbal description, or whether you think the verbal description is sufficient, depends mainly on what you choose to put in them. And for choosing, you should ultimately take into account which audience you are adressing with these models.